# Exibir opção selecionada em select com JS

Tags: javascript, html

Eu tenho um trecho de código onde eu desejo pegar o valor da `option` selecionada, com JavaScript, e dar um `alert` com esse valor. Entretanto, toda vez ele dá o valor como `undefined`. Eu fiz uma linha para colocar em um `input` também, só para testar, e não funcionou.

Aqui está o código:

```js
$("select[name='estado']").change(function() {
    var estado = document.getElementsByTagName("estado").value;
    document.getElementById("teste").setAttribute("value", estado);
    alert('estado ' + estado);
});
```

```html
<select id="txt-model" class="field-50" name="estado">
    <option value="">Selecione um Estado</option>
    <option value="AC">Acre</option>
    <option value="AL">Alagoas</option>
    <option value="AP">Amapá</option>
    //... O resto dos estados
</select>

<input type="text" id="teste" name="teste">
```

Comment: use $(this).val() para obter o valor no seletor.

Answer (score 5):

O *target* no seletor não está correto, uma forma é obter o valor direto pelo evento do elemento:

```js
$("select[name='estado']").change(function() {
    var estado = this.value;
    alert('estado ' + estado);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="txt-model" class="field-50" name="estado">
    <option value="">Selecione um Estado</option>
    <option value="AC">Acre</option>
    <option value="AL">Alagoas</option>
    <option value="AP">Amapá</option>
    //... O resto dos estados
</select>

<input type="text" id="teste" name="teste">
```

Um pouco sobre [seletores](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/cc288326(v=vs.85).aspx).